# Jquery Sum the value which has comma and if has decimal value then sum

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam trying to sum the div value that are comma separated and if has 2 decimal value then sum that decimal value and show if none of it has decimal value then show total.00 in final result but my code is giving me false calculation.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaikasifpasha3/9GVNT/27/)

HTML:

```
<div class=''>432.01</div>
<div class=''>4,12,412.01</div>
<div class=''>4,12,412.01</div>
<div class=''>12,41,241.01</div>
<span></span>
```

JS:

```
var sum = 0;
$('div').each(function() {
    var val = $(this).text().replace(',', '.');
    sum += parseFloat(val, 10);
});
$('span').text('result=' + sum);
```

Comment: parseFloat() doesn't take a second argument. What are the numbers you want to sum? Please give detailed examples.

Comment: parseFloat() is wrong please pass only one value

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace all the `commas` with empty `string` and do your calculation,

```
var sum = 0;

$('span').text('result=' + $('div').get().reduce(function(a,b){
  return a + parseFloat(b.textContent.replace(/,/g,""))
},0).toFixed(2));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9GVNT/29/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use RegExp in replace method to replace all ',' in strings.

```
var sum = 0;
$('div').each(function() {
    var val = $(this).text().replace(/,/ig, '');
    sum += parseFloat(val, 10);
});
$('span').text('result=' + sum);
```